# Application-specific file encryption in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, file, encryption

I need to develop some simple demonstration of an application reading a file over HTTPS and saving it to the local memory (internal or external) of an iOS device (e.g., an iPhone), in a way that it is only accessible to it. So, application-specific file encryption is required.

The ["Advanced App Tricks"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW11) page of the Apple iOS Developer Library, in the "Protecting Data Using On-Disk Encryption" section, seems to imply that a file encrypted on disk, via either Default (i.e., iOS filesystem) or "Complete" Data Protection, would be accessible by all applications, after the user types the device's lock code.

If that is the case, could someone please suggest the best way of implementing file encryption per-application on an iOS device, with a password request when a user tries to open the file? Any sample code would also be very helpful.

Also, does "software encryption" apply to iOS anymore? Both Default and Data Protection encryption seem to be hardware-based.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Application files are not accessible between Apps. Each App is individually sandboxed.

In all cases the document is talking about the access available to "Your App"/ It is never accessible to another App. But see below. Sone of the protection options help cover what and when "Your App" has access to the file when in the background.

JailBroken iOS devices will have greater file system access so adding "Data Protection" will protect from this vector.

See the document session on [The iOS Environment](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheiOSEnvironment/TheiOSEnvironment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH9-SW1) and particularly the section "The App Sandbox" iOS Environment

Hardware encryption: There are a few things that hardware encryption provide. 1. Speed. 2. The encryption method can not be changed, that is as with software encryption there is no code that  could be compromised. 3. The key can not be accessed. The key is in some manner placed/created in the hardware and the hardware will does not allow read access (there are occasionally very secure export capabilities). The device is asked to perform crypto functions on data and returns data. Examples of this are smart cards, HSMs, TPMs and TPM Equivalents, the iPhone has a TPM Equivalent and that is used for the Keychain.  By chance my wife and I were discussing this very topic yesterday. :-)

As far as I know, for encryption of bulk data, iOS does use special hardware instructions to aid AES encryption for speed but that would not be considered hardware encryption due to the key being available in software. There is a little guessing here due to the lack of information about the Apple A-series ARM chips, it is true of the Intel chips in Macs.

Comment: But surely, there are scenarios in which an attacker can read the entire contents of an iOS memory? How is that done despite application-specific sandboxing?

Comment: Only jailbroken devices. There are two (at least) CPU modes: Privileged (sometimes called Supervisor) and User at a minimum. Each has capabilities and User is restricted including physical memory access. Among other things these restrictions allow multi-user systems to operate and restrict access. Think web servers as one example.

Comment: But still, isn't it the case that in a jailbroken device, whoever knows the lock (PIN) and logs in, can access all the files, even if they are saved with Data Protection?

Comment: If the device is Jailbroken, the PIN is known and the attacker has physical access to the iOS device access could be available.

Comment: For security design a few things have to be determined. The value of the data to the developer, the device owner, the data owner and the attacker. What attacks are to be hardened against. How much difficulty of use the user will tolerate. The exploits to be secured. Then one can start developing a security plan. If you have real value you need to hire a security domain expert. Just having good encryption is not enough.